# Element DTD in XML

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm facing difficulties creating an ELEMENT DTD.

Here's what my ELEMENT looks like `ELEMENT I (P*, L?)` but after validating the DTD it returns

```
Element I: validity error : Element I content does not follow the DTD, 
expecting (P*, L?), got (L P P)
```

Here's the xml:

```
<I>
    <P></P>
<I>
<I>
    <P></P>
    <P></P>
<I>
<I>
    <P></P>
    <L></L>
<I>
<I>
    <L></L>
</I>
<I>
    <L></L>
    <P></P>
    <P></P>
</I>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your declaration for `I` says zero or more `P` **followed by** zero or one `L`. Your last `I` element has the `L` preceding the `P`.

If the XML is correct, you'll need to change your DTD. If the DTD is correct, you'll have to change your XML.

One possible DTD change is:

```
<!ELEMENT I ((P*,L?)|(L?,P*))>
```

Comment: I tried that too. Gives >> validity error : Content model of I is not determinist: ((P* , L?) | (L? , P*))

Comment: I knew that model was non-deterministic, but was hoping that wouldn't be an issue for your validator. What are you using to validate your xml?

Comment: Deterministic equivalent of Daniel Haley's proposal: `<!ELEMENT I ((P+,L?)|(L,P*))? >`

Answer (score 0):

Following allows both:

```
<!ELEMENT I ((P|L)*)>
```

or, if you prefer requiring one of `P` or `L` to occur, this should help:

```
<!ELEMENT I ((P|L)+)>
```